# Matlab assignment - return only odd elements

Tags: matlab, function

I wrote code similar to that posted by FeliceM, but when I tried to include the recommended changes/additions I got the following error:
**Warning: File: odd_index.m Line: 5 Column: 18
Function with duplicate name "odd_index" cannot be called.**

Here's my code:

```
function odd_index
  M=[1:5; 6:10; 11:15; 16:20; 21:25];
  M=M(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
end
function M_out = odd_index(M)
  M_out = M(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
end
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "Function with duplicate name "odd_index" cannot be called" the answer is right in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be simply a problem of naming your two functions the same name.  Rename the second function (and make sure it's in a separate file with the same name as itself).  Really, the first one isn't a function at all, but appears to be a script.

You may want to refer to the MATLAB Getting Started help documentation for more information on functions and scripts. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html